# Image Fusion using stationary wavelet transform (SWT) (MATLAB)

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matrix, wavelet

I'm trying to fuse two images using SWT. But I'm getting this error :

**The level of decomposition 1

and the size of the image (1,5)

are not compatible.

Suggested size: (2,6)**

**How to change the size of the image to make it compatible for transform?**

Code I've used is :

```
        clc
        i=1;
        fol=1;
        n=0;          


      for fol=1:5
      f='folder';
      folder = strcat(f, num2str(fol)); 
      cd(folder)
      d= numel(D);
      i=(n+1);
      Fname1 = strcat(int2str(i),'.bmp');
      Fname2 = strcat(int2str(i+1),'.bmp');

      im1 = imread(Fname1);
      im2 = imread(Fname2);

      im1=double(im1);
      im2=double(im2);
      % image decomposition using discrete stationary wavelet transform
     [A1L1,H1L1,V1L1,D1L1] = swt2(im1,1,'sym2');
     [A2L1,H2L1,V2L1,D2L1] = swt2(im2,1,'sym2');

     %  fusion start
     AfL1 = 0.5*(A1L1+A2L1);
     D = (abs(H1L1)-abs(H2L1))>=0;
     HfL1 = D.*H1L1 + (~D).*H2L1;
      D = (abs(V1L1)-abs(V2L1))>=0;
     VfL1 = D.*V1L1 + (~D).*V2L1;
     D = (abs(D1L1)-abs(D2L1))>=0;
      DfL1 = D.*D1L1 + (~D).*D2L1;

      % fused image
     imf = iswt2(AfL1,HfL1,VfL1,DfL1,'sym2');
     figure; 
     imshow(imf,[]); 
     Iname= strcat(int2str(fol),'.bmp');  
     imwrite(imf,Iname);
     end
```

Comment: That image is **really** small.  I'm assuming that's an image of size 1 x 5.  What happens when you do `size(im1)` and `size(im2)` in the command prompt, or inside that script?  You could always do `imresize` on the images to get it to that size... but still that image is very small.  Something is certainly not right.

Comment: Something size 1x5 should not even be allowed to be called "image".

Comment: @AnderBiguri - dat's ri bro. it shud be called matx.

Comment: Now I've changed the images and its working. Thanks for pointing it out @rayryeng

Comment: @rayryeng I've used imshow(imf,[]) for displaying the image. Empty matrix is used for data range. The image is displayed perfectly. In the next steps I'm trying to store that image imwrite(imf,Iname); This image is white in colour. Why is the image saved like this ? How to properly save the image ??

Comment: Ahhhh.  You need to normalize the image.  Let me right an answer.

Comment: @rayryeng I'll accept your answer. Help me out to save the image properly.

Comment: @PorkodiDevi - Done.  Take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address your first problem, that image is really small. I'm assuming that's an image of size 1 x 5.  I would suggest changing your image so that it's larger, or perhaps do an `imresize` on the image.  However, as what Ander said in his comment to you... I wouldn't call a 1 x 5 matrix an image.

To address your second problem, once you finally load in an image, the wavelet transform will most likely give you floating point numbers that are beyond the dynamic range of any sensible floating point precision image.  As such, it's good that you **normalize** the image first, then save it to file.

Therefore, do this right before you save the image:

```
%// ...
%// Your code...
imshow(imf,[]); 

%// Normalize the image - Change
imf = (imf - min(imf(:))) / (max(imf(:)) - min(imf(:)));

%// Your code again
%// Now save
Iname= strcat(int2str(fol),'.bmp');  
imwrite(imf,Iname);
```

The above transformation normalizes an image so that the minimum is 0 and the maximum is 1.  Once you do that, it should be visualized properly.  FWIW, doing `imshow(imf,[]);` does this normalization for you and displays that result, but it doesn't modify the image.

Comment: Now it is saving the images properly. Thanks for helping @rayryeng